# C-String array initialization - is this mutable?

Tags: c++, c-strings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifying C string constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants)
>   [Pointer to const char vs char array vs std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393291/pointer-to-const-char-vs-char-array-vs-stdstring)

I know I'm probably beating the dead horse with this question, but I'm a little confused and I haven't managed to find an exact answer on SO or google (that I'm confident is right - there's just too much information on C-strings to sift through).  Also, I've tagged it C++ because that's what I'm interested in, even though we're talking about C-style strings specifically.

In this situation:

```
char const a*  = "hello";
char const b[] = "goodbye";
```

I would have thought that "hello" and "goodbye" were both immutable strings because they come from string-literals that should decay to a char const*.

I've seen that in this particular case though, changing "hello" would be undefined while changing "goodbye" would be fine, assuming you stripped the constness from the b-array.

I assume that the string is mutable in the case of b due to the fact that its stored in a user-defined array.

*Are hello and goodbye different in this case?*  Is goodbye not a string-literal for some reason given this example.  Also, if goodbye isn't a string-literal, can I assume it isn't held in global memory, and the only reference to it after compile time is that which is left in the user-array cells?

Comment: Indirection operator `*` is located before the pointer identifier, like this `*a`

Comment: I'm not sure tagging a tag because you are interested in it is good enough reason. You could be interested in specifically C++ for Arduino, but this question would not deserve an `Arduino` tag.

Comment: C is (almost) a proper subset of C++, and I was programming in C++ at the time even though the question just focused on the C features of the language.  I don't see how me citing core language features relates to you citing a platform external to the language altogether.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first one creates a pointer that points to the string literal `"hello"`, which is probably stored in non-writable memory in the executable image of the program. Even if it isn't, you are not allowed to modify the contents of that array.

The second one creates an automatic array<sup>1</sup> (on the stack (usually, but that is implementation-defined)) and initialises it with the string `"goodbye"`. It is equivalent to

```
char const b[] = {'g', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'b', 'y', 'e', 0};
```

So while `"goodbye"` is immutable because it is a string literal which is `char const[8]` and stored in non-writable memory, the array `b` is an automatic<sup>1</sup> array that is immutable because you marked it `const`, but you could remove the `const` from the variable declaration to make the array's contents mutable. You are only *initialising the contents of the array* with the contents of the array `"goodbye"`.

You are not allowed to modify either of them because they are both `const char[]`, but the second one could be changed to `char[]` to be mutable, while the first one could not.

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106798/726361

---

<sup>1</sup> As R. Martinho Fernandes pointed out in the comments, the syntax `T x[] = ...` could also create a static array (not automatic but static (in the executable image usually, but that's implementation defined)) if it is at namespace scope, and it's only an automatic array otherwise.

Comment: The second one could create a static array if declared in namespace scope. It's only automatic if in function scope.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes updated, thanks (I hope I fixed it)

Comment: I initially misread "remove the `const`" as "remove the `const` with `const_cast`", not "remove the `const` from the declaration". The second is clearly fine while the first is undefined.

Comment: @MarkB: The first is _not_ undefined.

Comment: @MarkB actually you _can_ cast away the `const`ness of a truly `const` object, as long as you don't actually modify it (which is what Tomalak is referring to I think)

Comment: @Seth Carnegie Oh right good point - I was taking in the context of making it mutable which it still wouldn't be.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That's right. Casting away `const`ness from a valid object _never_ invokes UB; attempting to modify an immutable object (which you can usually only do after having casted away `const`ness) will.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was a very clear answer.  @LightnessRaces inOrbit - why is the first one "not undefined"?

Comment: @w00te he means that casting away the `const`-ness of a `const` object with `const_cast` is not undefined behaviour if you don't actually modify the object.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought he meant modifying it wasn't undefined.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

A string literal has type `char const[N]`; of course a name of this type may decay to a `char const*`.

Now:

1. A `char` array may be initialised by a string literal (8.5.2/1), and since you cannot otherwise copy or assign arrays, it follows that this initialisation implements a copy. You're free to do with the new, mutable array whatever you like.

   ```
   char str[6] = "hello";
   ```
2. Conversely, when initialising a pointer, you're obtaining a pointer that's the result of the string literal's immutable array type decaying.

   ```
   char const* str = "hello";
   ```

   There is no new array here. Just copying a pointer to the existing, immutable data.

Comment: I suppose in #2 you mean "(...) string literal's *immutable* array (...)", right?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Right :)

Answer (score 0):

They are different.  `a` points to a string literal that you cannot change.  However, `b` is an array of characters that is initialized with the given string.  Assuming the `const` were removed, then you can change the contents of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are different.

It is true that the string literals themselves (`"hello"` and `"goodbye"`) are immutable. However, when you are accessing `b`, you are not accessing your original `"goodbye"`. The code that you used declared a completely independent array `b`, which is only *initialized* with a string literal `"goodbye"`. Your 'b' is totally independent from the original string literal `"goodbye"`. Your `b` is a *copy* of that string literal. The only reason your 'b' is immutable is the `const` you explicitly included in its declaration. Remove that `const` and your `b` will become perfectly mutable, as any ordinary array is.

As for your 'a', it is a pointer that points directly to the original string literal `"hello"`. It is, of course, immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Both options *are* immutable, but not because they're created from a string literal. They're immutable because of the `const` keyword in the variable declarations.

You could also write `char c[] = "string_c";` and you would create a mutable copy (named `c`) of the literal `string_c`.

In your example about removing the constness of `b`, that may *appear* to work in some circumstances, but it's still illegal as far as the standard is concerned. Only objects that are truly non-const may be mutated.