# what is the valid assignment to string array pointer/ array name?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char a[] = "hello";
char *p = "world";
p = &a[1]; /* no 1, valid */
p[1] = &a[1]; /* no 2, invalid*/
p[1] = *a; /*no 3, invalid*/
a= p /* no 4, invaild */
```

In C, I thought `a[]` and `*p` was the exactly the same thing.
But, as the no 1 and 4 shows I found that you can't assign it to array name like `a`, when you can assign it to p since it's a pointer.
Is this the only difference between declaring string array in two different ways?
Having said that, if you can assign it to the pointer, why no 2 and no 3 are invalid?
Thank you.

Comment: Hint: What type is `p[1]`?

Comment: Another hint: a[] and *p are not exactly same thing. try sizeof a and sizeof p.

Comment: @niry I got 6 and 8, when I did sizeof a and p. can you explain why?

Comment: @tadman It's a char. But can you explain it why is it a constant?

Comment: Well, what type is `&a[1]`? Could you assign that to `char`?

Comment: @JessicaKim sure! `sizeof(a)` is 6 which it is the size of the array "hello" (5) plus null char '\0' (1). `sizeof(p)` is 8 which is the size of a pointer on a 64bit architecture (8 bytes * 8 bits = 64 bits)

Comment: @niry Ahh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays and pointers are not the same thing.  An array is a collection of identical objects, whereas a pointer points to one or more objecvts.  Where the confusion comes in is that an array name, when used in an expression, will in *most* cases decay into a pointer to the first element.  This means `a` and `&a[0]` evaluate to the same thing.

Looking at each case:

```
p = &a[1];
```

This is valid because `a[1]` is a `char` so `&a[1]` is a `char *`, which matches the type of `p`.

```
p[1] = &a[1];
```

Invalid, because `p[1]` has type `char` but `&a[1]` has type `char *`.  Also invalid at run time because `p` points to a string constant which can't be modified.

```
p[1] = *a;
```

The syntax is valid because both `p[1]` and `*a` have type `char`.  However, `p` points to a string constant which can't be modified so you end up with [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

```
a= p;
```

Invalid, because an array cannot be assigned to.

Comment: Thank you. But Why is p[1] a string constant, when a[1] is not?

Comment: [`char* x = "..."` is a constant string, but `char x[] = "..."` is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436781/c-string-array-initialization-is-this-mutable).

Comment: @JessicaKim `a` is an array which is initialized with a string constant.  It's elements contain the same values as the string constant but it's not the same object.  `p` on the other hand points to a string constant, so dereferencing `p` gives you an element of the string constant.